# Why can I not see color when a material is assigned?

Tags: materials, color

I am trying to make a new base color for the eyes of my seal. I have vertices groups for inner eyes and corneas making them easy to select. In edit mode, the inner eyes are dark grey. The dark grey color only shows up in edit mode! The eyeball in object mode is very light standard grey only in object mode, is this normal?

The eyeballs are dark grey because that was the color of the original material group `nose_eyelids`, which included  the `inner_eyeballs` vertices group. Although this color does not show up in any of the material previews on the material control panel!

What led to this result is this: First I reassigned the material group, not to include the inner_eye vertices group. And then I changed the color of the remaining material `nose_eyelids` to the dark blue color you can see in all the pictures. The dark color grey remains from the original selection as it was previously chosen. In object mode, the standard grey is showing up all along, though all the other colors have carried over between object mode and edit mode.

In an effort to resolve the problem, I created a new material and named it "eyball" (I should have named it "eyeball"). I assigned the new material to the `inner_eye` vertex group. The color as I decided to change it to white is displayed in the preview. The `inner_eye` vertex group can be selected and deselected from the material control panel. Yet, the chosen color white is not showing up. Still I have dark grey in edit mode and light grey in object mode.

However, this is the setup before I had assigned the new material to the inner_eye and maybe I would see the white as light grey anyways. In edit mode, the new color change is not showing up. It is like the new color choice has had no effect. Am I forgetting a step?

How come the constant dark grey color doesn't show up the same in both object and edit mode? And how come I am not seeing the change in color to white, although my material group is being selected and deselected successfully within the material control panel on my new material "eybal"? Maybe these pictures will help:

This is my seal head mesh and materials in progress in object mode:
[image: seal head mesh]

This is my seal head mesh and materials in progress edit mode cornea selected:
[image: cornea selected]

This is my seal head mesh and materials in progress edit mode:
[image: edit mode]